# Repeatedly slower internet on Mac only - fixes work temporarily

Tags: mac, network, wifi

My Internet connection speed (WiFi) keeps slowing down on my Mac. I usually get 250MBs, but it'll slow right down to about 20MBs. When I do a speed test with other devices on the same network they still get close to the full 250MBs.

The accepted answer on this [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323130/mac-wifi-slow-fine-on-other-devices) works for me, but only temporarily. If I follow the steps in the [OS X Daily article Fix Wi-Fi Problems in macOS Sierra](https://osxdaily.com/2016/09/22/fix-wi-fi-problems-macos-sierra/) the speed will be fine for about a day, then the same issue occurs.

Any insights  on what could be happening here and pointers to solve the problem would be massively appreciated.

Comment: The linked answer refers to other devices working fine; do have additional devices you can test with?  How are you measuring your speed.

Comment: Yes I tested on my iPhone and iPad, and speed is good on both of those while the Mac is far slower. I've just used fast.com to test.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a mac and had the same issue out of the box. I updated the OS and tried the same approach as what you've linked but turned out QOS on the router was turned off and came to full speed when I turned it on. Please give it a shot and tell me how it goes.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. The router is the only place to see the traffic speeds of each device and it’s not like the macOS needed any change to slow down and then speed up again. It goes as fast as the network allows it all the time. That’s how TCP works. [Unless there’s VPN on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408453/5472), it’s going to be the network or interference if it’s WiFi.