# Slow safari download speed with MacBookPro (Wifi and Lan)

Tags: network, safari, wifi, internet

As the title indicates I have huge problems when I want to download files with the Safari web browser. I have a MacBookPro late 2013 with macOS Catalina (10.15.7). I have to say that we basically have a very bad internet connection. Our provider promised a bandwidth from 6-16 Mbit/s but we only get approx. 2,5 Mbit/s when I run an internet speed test.

It is very strange because when I run an internet speed test with cable or wifi I get the value mentioned above. But when I download files with Safari the download speed drops down to approx. 0,2 Mbit/s and I don't know why. It happens both with wifi or cable no matter what I use. The speed test tells me every time that we should have a higher download rate.

Attached you'll find some additional info about our internet connection.

[image]

I already searched for help on the web and found this one: [Link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323130/mac-wifi-slow-fine-on-other-devices)

The first time I deleted the existing wifi preferences the speed went back to full speed. But after rebooting I had the same problems. Deleting them again has unfortunately not improved the situation.

I have the same issues with my iPadPro 3rd generation and iOS 14.3. The same download speed with the internet speed test and the same slow download speed when I download something with safari.

Additionally, I have to say, that sometimes I have the same download speed of 2.5 Mbit/s with the internet speed test and the actual download speed in safari. But most times of the day the download speed is slower than the measured one by the internet speed test.

I guess it should then be a problem with my router? For your information, we are using a Fritz!Box7430.

It really sucks especially when you want to download larger files ... I would be very grateful for any help. If you need additional information feel free to ask. Thank you very much.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Safari measures download speed in MB/s which is mega**bytes** per second, not mega**bits**. 0.2MB/s is 1.6mbps.

Comment: I already converted it from KB/sec in Mbit/sec. Actually I read a download speed of 20 KB/sec in Safari.